# 2020 election: The results are in!

Tags: cryptic-clues, seasonal

At the Puzzling Stack Exchange headquarters, we've received the first definitive knowledge of the results of the United States presidential election of 2020. And because this is Puzzling, we naturally present the results in a cryptic way. Who won?

The winning candidate was...

> At first tolerate, then back winner (5)

Representing the party that may be described as...

> Party briefly represented by 500 at the side of reem, regularly (3)

Those more familiar with the candidate may know him as...

> Extremely jaded Ohio electrician's name (3)

We congratulate the winner on his election to term number...

> Video-networking piece showing number (3)

Comment: [Now you should make a grid with it.](https://www.dailydot.com/unclick/clinton-1996-election-nyt-crossword-gif/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The trick to this puzzle is that

> there are two possible answers to each CC, and each answer represents a candidate in the 2020 US presidential election. (The question was posted before the result of that election was called.)

At first tolerate, then back winner (5)

> This is either `BIDE + _N = BIDEN` *or* `T_ + RUMP = TRUMP`.

Party briefly represented by 500 at the side of reem, regularly (3)

> This is either `D + _E_M = DEM` for Biden (Democrat) *or* `R_E_ + D = RED` for Trump (Republican, whose main color is red).

Extremely jaded Ohio electrician's name (3)

> This is either `J_ + O_ + E_ = JOE` for Joe Biden *or* `_D + _O + _N = DON` for Donald Trump.

Video-networking piece showing number (3)

> This is either `_ONE_ = ONE` for Biden (the challenger) *or* `_TWO_ = TWO` for Trump (the incumbent).

Comment: UGH I thought it was "rep" and I was wondering how the hell "P" could clue 500 ;_;

Comment: @oAlt Well, if the election was on SE, then voting for candidates from that party will give them rep, so I guess the answer could work?

Answer (score 2):

I guess HTM got the gist of the entire puzzle correct. The following is just my quick guess which solves only half of it.

---

> At first tolerate, then back winner (5)

> BIDEN; tolerate = BIDE, theN back

> Party briefly represented by 500 at the side of reem, regularly (3)

> DEM for democrat; 500 = D, rEeM regularly

> Extremely jaded Ohio electrician's name (3)

> JOE; Jaded Ohio Electrician

> Video-networking piece showing number (3)

> ONE; videO-NEtworking piece